# How do I solve this system of 2 equations?

Tags: systems-of-equations, quadratics

I need to solve for variables $u$ and $v$ in this system of equations:

$(x+u)^2+(y+v)^2=1$

$u^2+v^2=k$

How do I isolate $u$ and $v$ to get them both in terms of $x$, $y$, and $k$?

Comment: $u =\sqrt{ k - v^2}$. From there, substitution is your best bet.

Comment: Why did you delete then repost what's essentially the same question? The hint in my previous comment still stands as written: subtract the two equations and you get a linear equation in $u,v\,$. Use it to eliminate one of the variables, then substitute in either equation and solve the quadratic in the other variable.

Comment: @dxiv. I didn't know what I was asking before. I cleaned it up a little. I'll try doing some substitution methods but I'm having difficulty so far.

Comment: @dxiv:  my answer to this one sounds very close to what you suggested, though a slightly different way to express it.  Great minds think alike.

Comment: @RossMillikan Can only hope your answer works out better than my hint ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you expand the squares in the first equation, you can use the second to eliminate the $u^2,v^2$ terms.  That leaves you with one linear equation and one quadratic.  Solve the first for $u$ and substitute into the second.  That gives you a quadratic in $v$ which you can solve, getting two roots.  Plug them into the first and get two solutions for $u$.  Check them both and you are done.

Comment: What about the 2xu, 2yv terms? I've even tried to use SymboLab to solve it for me, but no luck

Comment: Those are the linear terms left after the quadratic ones disappear.  You essentially have $au+bv=c$ or $u=\frac 1a(c-bv)$.  Plug that into the second and you have the promised quadratic in $v$.

Comment: It gets more complicated as I do these things. Are you absolutely sure it is as simple as that?

Comment: Write it out in detail and see how it goes.  Yes, it works like that.